# ScaleAndAddTo in Eige GMEV

Tags: eigen

In order to provide matrix by vector multiplication, `Eigen` implements scaleAndAddTo operation which can be specialized for the users matrix type.

According to https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html
the user have to provide an specialization for scaleAndAddTo, which computes `dst += alpha * lhs * rhs`.

I have been following the call stack of until this is called and `Eigen` is doing the following:

```
  static EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void evalTo(Dst& dst, const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs)
  { dst.setZero(); scaleAndAddTo(dst, lhs, rhs, Scalar(1)); }
```

Since `dst` is set to zero, I can't understand why we need to provide a scaleAndAddTo instead of something like scale directly.

Why is the add part required?

Comment: Did you try what happens, if you just specialize `evalTo`?

Comment: This happens with MatrixXd and VectorXd multiplication. I dont understand why they waste time doing the setZero and doing the addAndScale for a very common type...

Comment: This should just be called for rather big GEMV, where the overhead does not matter, and just specializing `scaleAndAddTo` safes implementation effort/code duplication. For sufficiently small products Eigen should automatically call `lazyProduct`, which does not have this overhead.